Copy paste data when Windows is locked, or how can I directly get data to a userform from Outlook?
I have macro that runs when I get an email.
The idea is to copy the list in the email, open a workbook, open a userfrom, paste the data in the userform textbox, then run a macro.
All the above works when the computer is unlocked, but if I lock my computer then it fails with writing to the clipboard.
Outlook macro:
Sub Q_copy(msg As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim xExcelFile As String
    Dim xExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim bd As Variant
    
    'Debug.Print Trim(msg.HTMLBody)
    If Now() < msg.SentOn + TimeValue("00:01:00") Then ' make sure it doesn't trigger on yesterdays mail when I start the computer
 
        ' remove empty lines
        bd = Split(msg.Body, vbNewLine)
        j = 0
        For i = LBound(bd) To UBound(bd)
            If bd(i) <> "" And bd(i) <> " " Then
                bd(j) = bd(i)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
        ReDim Preserve bd(LBound(bd) To j - 1)
        ' empty lines removed

        bdtxt = Join(bd, vbNewLine)
        Dim MSForms_DataObject As Object
        Set MSForms_DataObject = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        MSForms_DataObject.SetText Trim(bdtxt)
        MSForms_DataObject.PutInClipboard ' here the code fails if the computer is locked, if I pull back the code two lines up to "Set..." and run again then it works.
        Set MSForms_DataObject = Nothing
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        On Error Goto 0
        
        If xExcelApp Is Nothing Then
            Set xExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        End If
        
        Set wb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("\\FS06\Users6\a78208\Dokument\Filtrera Quinyx.xlsm")
        xExcelApp.Visible = True
        xExcelApp.Application.Run "Modul1.test" ' opens a userform
        xExcelApp.Application.Run "Modul1.paste" ' this pastes data from clipboard to userform textbox
        xExcelApp.Application.Run "Modul1.leta_namn" ' uses the data in above textform
        'AppActivate "Filtrera Quinyx - Excel"
    End If
End Sub

The macro codes in the workbook:
Sub test()
    UserForm1.Show (0)
End Sub

Sub paste()

    Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard

    UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = DataObj.GetText(1)
    UserForm1.Palm.Value = True
End Sub

Sub leta_namn()

    UserForm1.CommandButton1_Click
End Sub

Obviously it would be better if Outlook could point the data directly to the userform textbox, but I have not found a way to do that.
Is it possible to point the data directly to a textbox in the userform, or is there some way to make the copy paste thing work while the computer is locked?
Or can I make the code wait for me to unlock the computer for maximum of say 30 minutes?

You could pass your data as a parameter to Application.Run.

I did not know this. That should work

@Andreas The Run method can even return a function's return value.
